# Updating table B when a row is selected in table A

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I've created several tables in my view controller. When I select a row in Table A I am taken, quite rightly, to TableA:didSelectRowAtIndexPath. There, I change the data source for table B but am unable to trigger anything that will cause it to be displayed.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    if tableView == tableA {

        //
        // 1. remove items from Table B data source
        //
        let recipeName = cell?.textLabel?.text
        ingredients.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        //
        // 2. change Table B data source contents
        //
        for var index = 0 ; index < ingredientInfo.count ; index++ {
            if ingredientInfo[index].itemName == recipeName {
                ingredients.append(ingredientInfo[index])
            }
        }

        tableView.reloadData()  // will reload Table A, I suspect but not Table B

    } else {

         // Table B
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
```

Any thoughts? I think what I'm essentially asking is how do I do a reloadData on Table B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect tableA and tableB are declared in your ViewController because you compare them in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. So you can call tableB.reloadData() directly as well as tableA.reloadData().